# Using Angular *ngFor in a CSS-Grid-Layout?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, css-grid, ngfor

I tried to use ngFor in a CSS-Grid-Layout. It didn't show me an Error but the Grid is not right generated.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div *ngFor="let info of infoCard; let i = index">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add the Grid after the Content is loaded it works fine. But when I try to generate the content in the Grid layout it doesn't work.

I only want to use grid-gap.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

Is there somthing I am missing?

Edit: I am using a dx-map from DevExtreme where my content is. So maybe thats the problem.

Comment: seems to work for here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-saxe7v

Comment: Maybe it behaves so odd because I am using dx-map with Google. Usually it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

**grid-gap** **is** **obsolete**. You can use row-gap, column-gap or gap instead.

Regarding grid distribution, have you tried grid-template-rows or grid-template-columns: auto ?

Comment: Yes I tried row-gap, column-gap but it behaved the same way. I also tried to define a grid with grid-template-rows or columns. But that didn't change anything.